# How do properties provide encapsulation?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I started learning C#, but I don't understand how properties provide encapsulation when the set method does not do any manipulation, validation, etc. My code:

```
class SitePage {
private string _specialString;
public string SpecialString
{
get { return _specialString; }
set { _specialString = value; }
}}
```

Here, instead of using the field _specialString, we are using the property SpecialString. Basically, instead of exposing the field, we are exposing the property. Why hide the field but expose the property to the client class?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the c# property, the compiler is automatically creating the the field in the background. Thus, whenever you *get* the property, it is using a method to retrieve the value stored in the underlying field. When you *set* the property, it is setting that underlying field.

Using the {get;set;} syntax is essentially a shortcut when you need a simple implementation.

The real benefit is when you need to exert control over *how* it gets or sets those values.

for example, you can make use of this syntax:

```
public SpecialString{get;private set;}
```

This will make it so that you can retrieve the value for the property from outside the class, but you can only set the value internally, using the class's own internal logic.

Or you could do something like this:

```
private string _specialString;
public string SpecialString{
    get;
    set{
        if(value.Length < 5)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            this._specialstring = value;
        }
}
```

Or you could trigger other methods to fire when you get or set a certain property. Think of properties as a gatekeeper. You can set whatever rules you want in order to let data pass in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the idea is that you usually want to return a copy. This becomes really important when you are handling sensitive data like tax information. You don't want just anyone or anything being able to access someone's tax information directly. A lot of programs won't NEED a system like this, but is still considered good practice just because it keeps you in the habit of it.

Going through an intermediary like this ensures that everything is done deliberately, and allows you to do some error checking only changing it, but not forcing it to run locally in the file. For instance, if you had a number that should never be negative, you could include an error check for that inside of your set method, instead of having to do that everywhere you use the variable.

If you need more detail or examples, just let me know. I don't feel like I explained that very well, but I hopefully explained it well enough to give you an rough idea as to why you would code this way.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, properties make up the public interface and fields are the backing data. You can also have an auto-implemented property by writing it like this:

```
public string SpecialString { get; set; }
```

This way, the compiler will build the backing field automatically.

There are other advantages to having a public property be the interface for a private backing field, like when you want to see if the value has changed and raise an event.

```
private string _specialString;

public string SpecialString
{
  get
  {
    return _specialString;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_specialString != value)
    {
      _specialString = value;
      OnValueChanged();
    }
  }
}
```